# How can I specify a predicate's type, which I won't know until runtime?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

My repository method fetches stuff from the database. It accepts the sort order as an argument:

```
IEnumerable<Car> getCars<TSortKey>(Expression<Func<Car, TSortKey>> sort);
```

I use `TSortKey`, because I won't know which property will be used until runtime, it could be `x => x.Name` or `x => x.Make` which are strings, but it could also be `x => x.History.Age` which is an integer.

The user chooses the sort order, then I set up the sort predicate in a switch and call into that method.

```
  Expression<Func<Car, object>> sortPredicate;
  switch (sortOption) {
    case SortOption.Name: sortPredicate = s => s.Name; break;
    case SortOption.Make: sortPredicate = s => s.Make; break;
    case SortOption.Age:  sortPredicate = s => s.History.Age; break;
    default:              sortPredicate = s => s.Name; break;
    }
  var cars = repo.getCars(sortPredicate);
```

I use `object` in the predicate, as I won't know the type until runtime. But that generates the wrong SQL, and throws.

So how can I fix this?

Comment: Possible solution: I can move the method call into each of the switch cases, but that gets very messy. e.g. `case SortOption.Name: cars = repo.getCars(x=>x.Name); break;`

Comment: I'm fairly sure your possible solution is the best one. Another possibility is just pass your `SortOption` enum into the repo and build the right lamda in place..

Comment: @Jamiec Yeah I'm doing the "messy" way right now, but it gets real messy as this is only a small excerpt of my real code. I'm hoping I can somehow rewrite the lambda to take a generic type instead.

Comment: You can think about using Reflection for creating your Expression-Function and create the generic method of getCars and invoke it. If you need some more help I could write an answer what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Expression<Func<T, object>>` generates additional `Convert` for value type properties, which EF does not like and throws `NotSupportedException`.

Instead of `OrderBy`, you can use the following helper method inside your repository class. What it does is stripping the `Convert` expression if needed and calling the  `Queryable.OrderBy` method dynamically:

```
public static partial class EFExtensions
{
    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> SortBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, object>> keySelector)
    {
        var body = keySelector.Body;
        if (body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert)
            body = ((UnaryExpression)keySelector.Body).Operand;
        var selector = Expression.Lambda(body, keySelector.Parameters);
        var orderByCall = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable), "OrderBy", new[] { typeof(T), body.Type },
            source.Expression, Expression.Quote(selector));
        return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)source.Provider.CreateQuery(orderByCall);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really great. I also added a `SortByDescending` method.

Comment: Is rewriting expressions like this as "slow" as reflection? I assume not, because you are not querying types and metadata, but rather creating something new. Is that correct?

Comment: I was sure you could do that! Although you could also just add `bool descending` argument to the above method and use `"OrderBy" + (descending ? "Descending" : "")` inside :)

Comment: Rewriting the lambda in this case is not like reflection, because  you are reusing the already built expression (body or body.Operand). What about the `Expression.Call`, that's exactly what `Queryable` methods do - [source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Linq/IQueryable.cs,7a2005ae434e9d9d)

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. Thanks again.