# Can't build lambda Expression with unknown type of a property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, expression-trees

I am building a helper method that returns an expression based on a property that could be used in an orderby or where, etc. in a linq to entities operation.

I won't know the type of the property upfront, so I have declared it as object and dynamic and have also tried to use `Expression.Convert` but it will not work for non string typed properties.

The current property type that is not a string that I'm working with is `int?` and the error I get is

> Expression of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object';

Code:

```
var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Employee), "x");
MemberExpression propExp = Expression.Property(param, "somePropertyName");
Expression.Lambda<Func<Employee, object>>(propExpression, param);
```

AS I said, I've used object and dynamic in line above with same results. I've also tried to convert it to the right type but that doesn't work:

```
Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(propExp, ((PropertyInfo)propExp.Member).PropertyType)
```

While I'm in debug mode and I try this, `Expression.Lambda(conversiona, param)`, it seems to work

```
{x => Convert(x.EmployeeNo)}
Body: {Convert(x.EmployeeNo)}
CanReduce: false
DebugView: ".Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[xx.DomainModel.Entities.Employee,System.Nullable`1[System.Int32]]>(xx.DomainModel.Entities.Employee $x)\r\n{\r\n    (System.Nullable`1[System.Int32])$x.EmployeeNo\r\n}"
Name: null
NodeType: Lambda
Parameters: Count = 1
ReturnType: {Name = "Nullable`1" FullName = "System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"}
TailCall: false
Type: {Name = "Func`2" FullName = "System.Func`2[[xx.DomainModel.Entities.Employee, Fng.Facts.DomainModel, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]"}
```

...but when I use it in an orderby I get

> error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression' to 'string'

I thought that maybe I needed to dynamically build the Expression.Lambda using the correct type as I inspect it but haven't tried that yet

Thanks for any help

Comment: Rather than trying to build an expression, try to build a whole `OrderBy(Descending)` / `ThenBy(Descending)` call. Otherwise you'll have the same issue as in [How can I specify a predicate's type, which I won't know until runtime?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40544393/how-can-i-specify-a-predicates-type-which-i-wont-know-until-runtime/40545008#comment68329807_40545008)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a string to create a EF order by expression?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39908403/how-to-use-a-string-to-create-a-ef-order-by-expression)

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to object by

```
Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(propExp, typeof(object))
```

That should be ok to be returned, but then you will have to deal with these converts on the other side, where you do the Orderby.

```
    private IQueryable<T> AddOrderBy<T>(IQueryable<T> query, Expression<Func<T, object>> orderByProperty, bool isAscending, bool isFirst)
{
    Expression<Func<IOrderedQueryable<int>, IQueryable<int>>> methodDef = isAscending 
        ? (isFirst ? (Expression<Func<IOrderedQueryable<int>, IQueryable<int>>>)(q => q.OrderBy(x => x)) : (Expression<Func<IOrderedQueryable<int>, IQueryable<int>>>)(q => q.ThenBy(x => x)))
        : (isFirst ? (Expression<Func<IOrderedQueryable<int>, IQueryable<int>>>)(q => q.OrderByDescending(x => x)) : (Expression<Func<IOrderedQueryable<int>, IQueryable<int>>>)(q => q.ThenByDescending(x => x)));

    // get the property type
    var propExpression = orderByProperty.Body.NodeType == ExpressionType.Convert && orderByProperty.Body.Type == typeof(object)
        ? (LambdaExpression)Expression.Lambda(((UnaryExpression)orderByProperty.Body).Operand, orderByProperty.Parameters)
        : orderByProperty;

    var methodInfo = ((MethodCallExpression)methodDef.Body).Method.GetGenericMethodDefinition().MakeGenericMethod(typeof(T), propExpression.Body.Type);
    return (IQueryable<T>)methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object[]{query, propExpression});
}
```

Comment: Thanks....the idea was to pass in a string property name to the method. Also, could it be turned into an extension method? Is it also possible to support IEnumerable too?

Comment: If you have a string as input, then you dont even have to worry about the convert, just say: 
    
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var propExpression = Expression.Lambda(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(param, propertyName), param);
and then use that in the invoke

Comment: For IEnumerables, I guess its the same code, question is if your db supports it ???